# Conservation of Linear Momentum with respect to a given direction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, vectors, linear-algebra

Is linear momentum conserved in any direction? More specifically, if you project all momentum vectors in a system onto another vector, will momentum be conserved?

I know that momentum is conserved along the $x$ and $y$ axes, so I'm expecting this to be true, but I have yet to see a rigorous proof.

Comment: Comment to the question(v1): Are you considering an _isolated_ system?

Comment: yes, it is an isolated system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is.

The **total** momentum vector of a system doesn't change at all (constant length *and* direction), so the projection of it on a line (or any function you apply to it) won't change. Projection is a *linear* operator, so that if you project each particle's momentum on a line and then sum, you get the same result as summing first (to get the total momentum) then projecting.

Answer (score 1):

In Euclidean geometry (as in classical mechanics), the axes are independent of each other; so yes, momentum is conserved along any vector.  Really though -- [when you factor in general relativity -- not so much](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/GR/energy_gr.html).